# __kernel_rt_sigreturn - react native

Tags: android, react-native

The following error is found in firebase crashlytics for the app released as react native.
Could you tell me how to solve it?

```
main (native):tid=1 systid=20550 
#00 pc 0xa2adc libc.so (__rt_sigsuspend + 12)
#01 pc 0x61098 libc.so (sigsuspend + 56)
#02 pc 0x858034 split_config.arm64_v8a.apk 
#03 pc 0x678 [vdso] 
#04 pc 0xa30b8 libc.so (__epoll_pwait + 8)
#05 pc 0x17ea8 libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int) + 184)
#06 pc 0x17d84 libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**) + 116)
#07 pc 0x159170 libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int) + 48)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

I've tried several stackoverflows and web surfing, but I couldn't find a solution.
Please let me know if there is a tool that can test the error of android because it is an app made with react native.
Thank you in advance.